# bootstrap 4, list-group, search all BUT SHOW LIMITED LINES

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, listgrid

I have a script, it shows database-rows as list-group with a searchbar.
Yes, it works.

But the database has about 10.000 rows.
I want to show only the first 5 rows in the list-group, but I want to use for search all rows.

```
    <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
   <?
      if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
      
      /* fetch object array */
      while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
      if ($show_row < 6) echo "<li class='list-group-item'>$row[0]</li>"; // show row
      if ($show_row > 5) echo "<li class='list-group-item'>$row[0]</li>"; // hide row, but use it for search
          $show_row++;
      }
      }
      ?>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for answers ;-)

Comment: Just add a attribute style="display:none;" or a class for hide it in css ?

Comment: Hi Inazo,

o.k., it works for the first list, but after searching shows it all filtered rows (more as 5)

Comment: What about a LIMIT in filter-funktion?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do with what you have is use CSS `display:none` on rows that you do not want to initially display, then reset to the original state if there is no input. I would also pre-digest the searchable values and insert them as data attributes in the `li` tags, so that you don't have to calculate that in real time for each item during the search.

```
<ul class="list-group" id="myList">
    <?php
    if ($result = $conn->query($sql))
    {
        /* fetch object array */
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row())
        {
            /*
                Pre-digest the searchable string so we don't have to do this in JS for every comparison
                Set this as a data attribute in the li tag
                If you need something more than just strtolower, think about encapsulating this in a function.
            */
            $currSearchableValue = strtolower($row[0]);

            /*
             * Set any rows after the first 5 to display: none
             * Alternatively, you could just insert them all into the page displayed, then use JS to hide the rows,
             * but the user would see the list briefly, and the page contents would jump, which is amateur hour stuff.
             */
            $currStyleAttr = ($i>=5) ? ' style="display: none"':'';

            echo '<li class="list-group-item" data-searchable="'.$currSearchableValue.'"'.$currStyleAttr.'>'.$row[0].'</li>';
            $i++;
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var $listItems = $("#myList li");
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function ()
        {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

            // Only search if we have input, otherwise reset the list
            if(value.length>0)
            {
                $listItems.filter(function()
                {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).data("searchable").indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $listItems.hide().slice(0, 5).show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @ Rob
It works, but it's slow, there are to many datarows.

Comment: I'll make it without live-saerch.

Comment: Yeah, you don't really want to shove 10K rows over the wire and into the page. Can you accept the answer though?